# Problems with using freestyle and array modifier together and freestyle clipping through objects

Tags: modifiers, freestyle

I'm relatively inexperienced and am having trouble figuring out how to remove the freestyle lines between array duplicates. I'm also having trouble with freestyle going through objects
[image: 1]

the building and street are both made from array modifiers, I can easily fix the street by making it one long object instead of using an array modifier but the building would be a lot harder to fix

I followed a tutorial to get the shaders and freestyle outlines to look this way

Does anyone know how to fix either of these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, there is a mesh of faces at the juncture of the array.
That face should penetrate and describe a line like a border.

If you remove it, the extra mesh will not appear.

[image]

If you must have extra lines, prepare a separate layer,
and add edge marks to the edges.
After that, you can composite the image separately by compositing.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aTCMWnJKpE&t=367s